# Grails, paging doesn't work when using findAllByxx to get index-list

Tags: grails, pagination, gsp

When I look at index.gsp for OfferHeader I get only the "Previous" button and when clicking on it until it finds the top the button disappear.
The trouble is that I need to use the findAllBy-list to get a filtered listing so the respond can look like this:

```
respond offerHeader, model:[offerHeaderCount: offerHeader.count()]
```

because offerHeader.count() is not allowed so I used .size() instead.

Controllers index look like this:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def offerHeader = OfferHeader.findAllByOfferType('o',params)
    def count = offerHeader.size()
    respond offerHeader, model:[offerHeaderCount: offerHeader.size()]
}
```

### Amendment

Hmm Grails doesn't like me..

I got this error:

```
URI
    /offerHeader/index
Class
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
    null
Caused by
    No such property: createCriteria for class: com.torntrading.portal.OfferHeader

Around line 15 of grails-app\controllers\com\torntrading\portal\OfferHeaderController.groovy

12:
13:    def index(Integer max) {
14:        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
15:        def offerHeader = OfferHeader.createCriteria.list( params ) { eq ( "offerType", "o" )}
16:
17:        def count = offerHeader.size()
18:        respond offerHeader, model:[offerHeaderCount: offerHeader.totalCount
```

### EDIT

creteCriteria should be used like this:

```
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def offerHeader = OfferHeader.createCriteria().list( params ) { eq ( "offerType", "o" )}

        def count = offerHeader.size()
        respond offerHeader, model:[offerHeaderCount: offerHeader.totalCount]

    }
```

Comment: Well, I got some error using createCriteria see my amendment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A criteria query can be better is this scenario:

```
def offers = OfferHeader.createCriteria().list( params ) {
    eq ( "offerType", "o" )
}

respond offers, model: [offerHeaderCount: offers.totalCount]
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I tried this. For mee it was not a surprise that I got to many pages as it also counted the rows that was filtered. So I got one more page than expected  e.g. 4 instead of 3 so the last page was empty. Otherwise the paging worked well in that case but as you understand I can not have it like that.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I had to put () after createCiteria See my edits. Maybe you should edit your answer so I can "Accept" it.